# Understanding "well founded" proofs in Coq

Tags: theory, coq

I'm writing a fixpoint that requires an integer to be incremented "towards" zero at every iteration. This is too complicated for Coq to recognize as a decreasing argument automatically and I'm trying prove that my fixpoint will terminate.

I have been copying (what I believe is) an example of a well-foundedness proof for a step function on Z from the standard library. [(Here)](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.ZArith.Zwf.html)

```
Require Import ZArith.Zwf.

Section wf_proof_wf_inc.
  Variable c : Z.
  Let Z_increment (z:Z) := (z + ((Z.sgn c) * (-1)))%Z.

  Lemma Zwf_wf_inc : well_founded (Zwf c).
  Proof.
    unfold well_founded.
    intros a.
  Qed.

End wf_proof_wf_inc.
```

which creates the following context:

```
  c : Z
  wf_inc := fun z : Z => (z + Z.sgn c * -1)%Z : Z -> Z
  a : Z
  ============================
  Acc (Zwf c) a
```

My question is what does this goal actually mean?

I thought that the goal I'd have to prove for this would at least involve the step function that I want to show has the "well founded" property, "Z_increment".

The most useful explanation I have looked at is [this](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/Inductive-and-Co-Inductive-Types) but I've never worked with the list type that it uses and it doesn't explain what is meant by terms like "accessible".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you don't need to do a well founded proof, you just need to prove that your function decreases the (natural number) abs(z). More concretely, you can implement `abs (z:Z) : nat := z_to_nat (z * Z.sgn z)` (with some appropriate conversion to nat) and then use this as a measure with `Function`, something like `Function foo z {measure abs z} := ...`.

The well founded business is for showing *relations* are well-founded: the idea is that you can prove your function terminates by showing it "decreases" some well-founded relation `R` (think of it as `<`); that is, the definition of `f x` makes recursive subcalls `f y` only when `R y x`. For this to work `R` has to be *well-founded*, which intuitively means it has no infinitely descending chains. CPDT's [general recursion chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.GeneralRec.html) as a really good explanation of how this really works.

How does this relate to what you're doing? The standard library proves that, for all lower bounds `c`, `x < y` is a well-founded relation in `Z` if additionally its only applied to `y >= c`. I don't think this applies to you - instead you move towards zero, so you can just decrease `abs z` with the usual `<` relation on `nat`s. The standard library already has a proof that this relation is well founded, and that's what `Function ... {measure ...}` uses.